# I can't save user records to complete a multiple choice survey

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, nested, survey

There is a brilliant railscast about creating surveys:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

It's everything I need to create the survey, but I want users to sign in a complete one or more surveys at a time on a single page.

Can anyone expand on this tutorial to store answers for a multiple choice survey? is there a good tutorial?

---

**Below is my attempt**

I'm using Devise for user accounts.

```
User
has_many :answers_users
has_many :answers, through: :answers_users
has_many :questions, through: :answers_users
has_many :surveys, through: :answers_users

Survey
 has_many :questions, autosave: true
 has_many :answers_users, autosave: true
 has_many :users, through: :answers_users
 has_many :answers, through: :questions

question
belongs_to :survey
has_many :answers
has_many :answers_users
has_many :users, through: :answer_users

Answer
belongs_to :question
has_many :users, through: :answers_users, autosave: true

AnswersUsers
 belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :answer
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :survey
```

My form

```
<%= simple_form_for [current_user], :url => competition_enter_path, :method => :POST do |f| %>

    <% @surveys.each do |survey| %>

              <%= survey.name %>
              <br />
              <% survey.questions.each do |qq| %>
          <%= simple_fields_for qq do |q| %>
                  <h3><%= qq.question %></h3>
                  <%=   q.association :answers,
                                      label: false,
                                      collection: qq.answers,
                                      as: :"#{qq.question_type.code}",
                                      :label_method => :answer,
                                      required: true
                  %>
              <% end %>

              <% end %>


          <% end %>
          <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit %>
          </div>

      <% end %>
```

The output I'm getting here is (with one answer)

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SOUAVgw261HrMLUxkVQvlKrigSStZs+uHqHePizgBxE=", "question"=>{"answer_ids"=>"11"}, "commit"=>"Update User", "competition_id"=>"1"}
```

But nothing is saving. I don't know what to put in the controller as I need to work back on the answer to also store the Question_id and Survey_id, right?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Careful about asking for tutorials here - such requests are considered "out of scope" for SO, and might get your question flagged!

Comment: Thank you, I've been a member here for a while now and I still don't have a clue what I'm "allowed" to write and and I'm not.

Comment: This question is within scope as a whole... IMO some people flag without reading things all the way through, though. The help center has a page regarding questions (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and is a GREAT resource for questions about site operation. Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks Bro, now if only someone would answer :)